# Undefined not a function: how to get LABjs to work with jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, labjs

I'm trying to improve the load time of my web page using LABjs. However I'm getting 'Undefined not a function' in relation to jQuery.cookie('mycookie') which I'm using in my own jQuery script.

I'd be grateful for some advice on how to implement LABjs to deal with this as I don't quite understand the documentation.

Here's the code I have so far:

**HTML**

I have jQuery and LAB.min.js in the footer of my HTML page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfolder/jquery1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfolder/LAB.min.js"></script>
```

**LAB.min.js file**

Here I load my scripts in order. ratings.js depends on jquery-cookie.js, so I've included a wait() first to make sure that jquery-cookie.js is loaded first.

```
//ALL THE LABjs code is here, but not included on this post!

$LAB.setGlobalDefaults({Debug:true});
.script("myfolder/bootstrap.min.js")
.script("myfolder/jquery-cookie.js") 
.wait() 
.script("myfolder/ratings.js");
```

**ratings.js**

ratings.js is a long piece of code contained within the jQuery(document).ready function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 //LOTS OF CODE HERE
    if(jQuery.cookie('mycookie')==null){    
        //LOTS OF CODE HERE
    }   
//LOTS OF CODE HERE
});
```

I'm getting an error in ratings.js relating to the line of code containing jQuery.cookie('mycookie'). It says "Uncaught type error: undefined is not a function"

From what I understand, jQuery.cookie() isn’t yet defined when I try to pass it to .wait(). What is the best way to get this to work, keeping in mind that I want to keep ratings.js in a separate js file because it contains a lot of code and is one of many similar js files that also throw up the same error when I load them with LABjs.

Many thanks!

Katie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove the link to jQuery in your HTML and just have LABJS to load all of the scripts. This will load jQuery before Bootstrap or your plugin:

```
$LAB
  .setGlobalDefaults({Debug:true}) // removed semi-colon
  .script("myfolder/jquery1.9.1.js")
  .wait()
  .script("myfolder/bootstrap.min.js")
  .script("myfolder/jquery-cookie.js") 
  .wait() 
  .script("myfolder/ratings.js");
```

(Note that you had a semicolon in your code that was likely breaking something too):

Comment: Thanks Andy - good spot re. the semi colon - I've now removed that! 

I've tried coding the page exactly as you've suggested, but now I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. So I guess it's not even getting a chance to know that the cookie is not defined because it can't get past the fact that jQuery isn't defined.

Comment: I'm not sure what that's about. [I've managed to replicate your setup](http://www.sendspace.com/file/afjjau) (zip file, contains just JS files and an HTML file - just unzip into a new folder and doubleclick the html file with the console open you should see 'My name is Bob' appear) and it works fine with that semicolon removed. Can you check in the console that it's finding and loading jquery and that it's not misnamed?

Comment: Hi Andy - thanks so much for this. Knowing that it works for you and seeing it work for myself using your example has helped me debug what's going on. I had a list of scripts in my HTML and was gradually moving them across to load with LABjs, one by one. However, it appears that you can't load scripts normally if they depend on something loaded with LABjs. e.g. if you load jQuery with LABjs and then load ratings.js normally, it won't work. You have to load them both with LABjs. Thanks again Andy - I can now see how to get it to work!